# Принимать сообщение при условии. PyTelegramBotApi

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Как можно сделать так, чтобы бот видел введет ли пользователь цифру, когда нажмёт на Inline кнопку "Ввести цифру"? Использую библиотеку PyTelegramBotApi, он же telebot

```
@client.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def command_handler(message):
    Markup_inline = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
    BtnYes = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Ввести цифру", callback_data="Yes")
    BtnNo = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Не вводить цифру", callback_data="No")
    Markup_inline.add(BtnNo, BtnRefYes)
    client.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выбери да или нет', reply_markup = Markup_inline)

@client.callback_query_handler(func = lambda call: True)
def Answer(call):
    Markup_Inline = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
    if call.data=='Yes':        
        client.edit_message_text('Введи цифру', call.message.chat.id, call.message.message_id, reply_markup = Markup_Inline)
        @client.message_handler(content_types = ['text'])
        def Answer2(message):
            if (message.text).isdigit():
                print('цифра введена')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Опечатка:

**BtnYes** `= types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Ввести цифру", callback_data="Yes")`
`Markup_inline.add(BtnNo,` Btn**Ref**Yes`)`

и

```
@client.message_handler(content_types = ['text'])
def Answer2(message):
    if message.text.isdigit():
        print('цифра введена')
```

расположить под `@client.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)`

полный код:

```
import telebot
from telebot import types

client = telebot.TeleBot('9:AAE')

print(client.get_me())


@client.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def command_handler(message):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
    yes = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Ввести цифру", callback_data="Yes")
    no = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Не вводить цифру", callback_data="No")
    markup.add(no, yes)
    client.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выбери да или нет', reply_markup=markup)


@client.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def answer(call):
    if call.data == 'Yes':
        client.edit_message_text('Введи цифру', call.message.chat.id, call.message.message_id)


@client.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def answer2(message):
    if message.text.isdigit():
        print('цифра введена')


client.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

Но имейте в виду, что если ввести цифру без нажатия кнопки, то всё равно сработает `print('цифра введена')` т.к. `@client.message_handler(content_types=['text'])` ловит любой текст отправленный боту.

Чтобы `print('цифра введена')` срабатывал только после нажатия кнопки и ввода сообщения:

```
@client.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def answer(call):
    if call.data == 'Yes':
        msg = client.edit_message_text('Введи цифру', call.message.chat.id, call.message.message_id)
        client.register_next_step_handler(msg, answer3)


def answer3(message):
    if message.text.isdigit():
        print('цифра введена после кнопки')
```